# check if string contains only alphabets in python

Tags: python, regex

I have strings in this form: string space string space string

```
, test ,
test test1 test2
[ test test1
```

What I want is for all the three strings to only have alphabets, and if it does not then return false, I tried isalpha but that does not give correct results.

oops this was easy, I think I got it working with :

```
re.match('[a-zA-Z]* [a-zA-Z]* [a-zA-Z]*$ ', the_string)
```

Comment: Can you show the sample code you tried?

Comment: Have you considered `isalpha()`?

Answer (score 1):

Your regex will only work if there are two spaces in the string and will return true even if the beginning of the string contains invalid characters.

If your desired characters are alphabet, numbers and whitespace try

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*$
```

If you only want alphabet characters and whitespace try

```
^[a-zA-Z\s]*$
```

If you don't want to match an empty string then replace the * with a +